# Unable to contact Juno download site

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-juno, m2e

I am trying to download m2e for Eclipse Juno but for some reasons I have problems contacting the update site.

I was not able to download from the marketplace, which claimed dependencies are missing.
Then I tried to use the Juno update site (under install new software...) but received this error :

```
Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno/.
Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno/.
No repository found at http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno/201209280900.
```

What is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was to a use the site shown in the error with the addition of '/'

```
http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno/201209280900/
```